# How i can run one function with different inputs at same time?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to my question.
I have a function that has a while loop in itself to gets his results. I want to use about 600 inputs at the same time for that function or at least group them in smaller inputs.

Here is the function I am trying to use but does not run all 600 inputs and it gets results one by one.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from subfunction import myfunc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    agents = 600
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=agents)
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        pool.map(myfunc(list1[i],list[i]))
```

Comment: You're misunderstanding how to use `Pool.map` - *it* does the looping for you, you call it once with lists of parameters to be used.  Try `pool.map(myfunc, zip(list1, list))`.  Currently, you are calling `myfunc()` yourself, in the main process, so there's no parallelization at all.  Note that 600 processes is way too many, you want something comparable to the number of cores your CPU has.

Comment: thank you so much,{pool.map(myfunc, zip(list1, list))} worked for me

Comment: Have you checked the multiprocessing docs?

Comment: actually I'm not a professional programmer. for my work, I had to write a small program. I amusing whatever I got from the internet.